# GIMP memory increasing problem

Tags: 14.04, ram, gimp

I have a problem with GIMP in Ubuntu 14.04. When starting GIMP it works perfectly at first, but as soon as I copy a selection of pixels value in "system monitoring > resources > memory and swap history > memory" (hope those terms are correct, had to translate them) starts to increase and it doesn't stop until the memory reaches values bigger than 95%, which dramatically decreases the performance of my operating system. After closing GIMP the memory value suddenly decreases to some value below 30%. Something else I realized: as soon as the memory starts to increase, the cursor in GIMP changes to a busy cursor (or hourglass cursor or whatever it is called) for a very short period of time and this cursor change happens approximately once each second. I assume that GIMP is saving something each second, even though I don't actively save anything. I also assume that it has something to do with the clipboard since if I execute "xsel -bc" in a terminal, the memory increase stops (but does not reduce to its initial value).

Help would very much be appreciated!

Comment: How big is the "selection of pixels" you copy, and how exactly do you do it?

Comment: I copied selections of only a few pixels up to a million pixels, it's the very same effect that happens.

Comment: I stand corrected, it actually makes a big difference if I copy a few pixels only or a million pixels. The behaviour described above happens when I copy about a million pixels. If copying smaller sections the memory increase happens much slower.

Comment: The copying is done by "Ctrl + C"

Answer (score 0):

We've seen a problem with similar symptoms reported as https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699625

There, the clipboard link grabbing of jdownloader continued to increase the memory usage of GIMP. If you use this tool, or something else that accesses the clipboard (KDE's klipper used to cause the same, IIRC), then you might be able to work around the problem by disabling those.

Whether the problem is in GIMP or GTK+ - the UI framework - has not been determined yet.